Postgresql, Migrar schema public a un nuevo Schema
Consulta. Tengo objetos como tablas, procedimientos, vistas y dominios en el esquema Public. Por temas de seguridad, quiero migrar todos esos objetos a un esquema con un nombre diferente y sacarlos del Public. ¿Cuál vendría a ser la mejor práctica para mover datos y objetos del esquema 'Public' dentro de una misma base de datos? ¿Se puede renombrar el esquema Public? Si es así, ¿qué debería tener en cuenta antes de renombrarlo? Mi idea es tratar de no usar un dump. ¡Desde ya, muchas gracias!

en primer lugar no me parece una buena idea renombrar el esquema public, lo que puedes hacer (si tienes espacio en tu equipo), hacer un dump de ese esquema:
pg_dump --file <path_y_nombre_de_salida> --host <nombre_del_host> --port <puerto_donde_escucha> --username <usuario> --format=p --inserts --schema=public <base_de_datos>

esto te va a generar un archivo plano, luego puedes editarlo y modificar el CREATE SCHEMA public (está al principio) por tu nuevo esquema, reemplazar la cadena " public." por el nombre de tu nuevo esquema y de esa forma vas a realizar una copia de public en tu nuevo esquema.
Luego con psql lo levantas:
psql --host <nombre_del_host> --port <puerto_donde_escucha> --username <usuario> -W -f <path_y_nombre_de_salida>

y por último deberías eliminar los objetos que estaban en public.
Saludos
